# Error between view and controller which I can not find

Tags: php, laravel

Today I found a problem in my app and have not found a solution yet.

The problem is, I have a view with a form where records you have previously selected, then need to select a new state to then update the records, but I get the error when I run the submit button . ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I don't see the problem but I think it's something simple I'm missing.

I already tried delete browser cache and route cache.

```
// this is the form
<form action="{{ route('handovers.updateData') }}" method="POST">
@csrf
<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Handover Date</th>
        <th>Inventory Number</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Choose a status</th>

    </tr>

        
    @foreach($handovers as $handover)
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="handoversid[]" value="{{ $handover->id }}">
            <td>{{ $handover->employee->Firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $handover->employee->Surname }}</td>
            <td>{{  date('d.m.Y', strtotime($handover->Handover_Date)) }}</td>
            <td><a href=" {{ route('devices.edit', $handover->Device_id ) }}">{{$handover->device->Inventory_id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $handover->device->devicemodel->Model }}</td>
            <td> <select name="ddStatus[]">
                    <option value="default">Select a Status</option>
                    @foreach($availableStatuses as $avStatus)
                        <option value="{{ $avStatus->id }}"> {{ $avStatus->Status_Name }} </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select></td>
        </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
    <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
<a href="{{ route('activeHandovers') }}" ><button type="button">Cancel</button></a>
</form>


<form action="{{ route('handovers.pdf') }}" method="POST" target="_blank">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="handovers" value="{{ $handovers }}">
    <button type="submit">Download PDF</button>
</form>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/handovers/offboarding', [HandoverController::class,'getActiveHandovers'])->name('activeHandovers');
Route::get('admin/handovers/search', [HandoverController::class,'search'])->name('handovers.search');
Route::post('admin/handovers/offboarding/selected', [HandoverController::class,'offboarding'])->name('handovers.selected');
Route::get('admin/handovers/offboarding/selected', [HandoverController::class, 'offboarding'])->name('selectedReturns');

Route::post('admin/handovers/updateData', [HandoverController::class, 'updateData'])->name('handovers.updateData');

Route::post('admin/handovers/offboarding/pdf', [PDFController::Class, 'generatePDF'])->name('handovers.pdf');


Route::Resources([
    'devices' => DeviceController::class,
    'admin/types' => TypeController::class,
    'admin/locations' => LocationController::class,
    'admin/devicemodels' => DevicemodelController::class,
    'admin/handovers' => HandoverController::class
]);
```

HandoverController@updateData

```
public function updateData(HandoverFormDataRequest $request)
    {
        /* does not work properly
        $request->validate([
            'ddStatus.*' => 'required|not_in:default',
        ]);*/

        $handovers = $request->input('handoversid');
        $statuses = $request->input('ddStatus');

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($handovers); $i++) {
            $handover = Handover::find($handovers[$i]);
            $status = $statuses[$i];

            Device::where('id',$handover->Device_id)->update([
                'Status_id' => $status
            ]);

            $handover->update([
                'Return_Date' => Carbon::now()
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('activeHandovers')->with('success', 'The devices were successfully returned or moved to the offboarding');
    }
```

Comment: What does you `HandoverFormDataRequest` look like? Is there anything weird going on in there?

Comment: And does the `activeHandovers` happen to redirect as well?

Comment: @damask I'm 10000% sure I tried yesterday without the HandoverFormDataRequest but it didn't work, but now it works for whatever reason! Thank you I wouldn't tried it anymore I guess. I still had wrong validation statements that I don't need here, but how can I validate that a status has been selected?